# Selection Bias and Controlling Covariates

Tags: r, regression, modeling, confounding

I am currently performing a retrospective study that is comparing a surgical procedure vs a modified version of the same procedure. There is obvious selection bias because of the selection criteria necessary to perform the modified procedure. I was wondering how I would control for these 3 variables (all are simple T/F requirements)? Should I just perform a logistic regression for each dependent variable we are investigating and hope none of them reach significance? Or is there a statistical test that automatically adjusts for these 3 selected covariates?

Initially I did not perform any statistical tests between these groups for this reason, but if we were to prove that these variables are not confounding then I could simply perform the appropriate two sample test, correct?

My Data:

- Independent Variable (2 groups) = Procedure 1, Procedure 2
- We also have multiple dependent variables we want to compare between the two groups: Numerical and Logical (e.g. Length of Stay,
  or Re-operation within 30 days, etc.)
- But I have 3 Logical variables that I am afraid are confounding.

PS. I'm using R to carry out this analysis and any reference to R functions would be a plus.

Comment: (Just thinking through this myself, quick thoughts and questions) Based on the 3 T/F questions, we can group individuals into $2^3 = 8$ buckets. Within each bucket, was there random assignment of individuals to (1) normal procedure or (2) modified procedure? Was the selection of individuals to either normal or modified procedure purely a function of observed variables (eg. the 3 T/F questions) or is there the potential for unobserved factors going into the decision to receive normal or modified? Is there enough data to estimate the difference in treatment and control for each of the 8 buckets?

Comment: The selection of individuals was not random. For example, if the patient was TRUE for any of the 3 variables then they were excluded from the modified procedure. I dont think there would be unobserved factors going into the decision because it was a decision algorithm that decided whether the patient would receive one procedure over the other. If we were to divide the patients into 8 buckets, it would not be equally distributed, there would be definitely more patients in the 3xFALSE group. PS Thanks for your response!

Comment: To the extent there's concern that the 3 T/F questions are associated with outcomes, the apple to apples comparison is to compare outcomes between modified and original among people that were F on all 3 questions. If among 3F people, it's effectively random who did or did not receive the modified procedure, that's great. The standard concern in selection situations is there's selection on unobservables, that unobservables aren't evenly distributed among those that did and did not receive treatment because unobservables drove the treatment decision.

Comment: (Disclosure: I'm an econ/finance guy, and I don't have a great sense of what the important vs. unimportant statistical issues are in specifically medical situations) Note: If you want to use individuals that were T on one or more questions to construct a pseudo control group (eg. because there aren't many people in 3F who received original treatment), then it gets more tricky... it requires additional assumptions.

Comment: There are a few patients that did receive the regular procedure even if they met the criterion for modified procedure, does that help these are only a couple? On another note, If I was able to generate a logistic regression and prove that none of the 3 variables had any influence on the dependent variables then would it be safe to perform a simple 2 sample test for the dependent variables?